# UISlider occasionally stops dragging

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UISlider` positioned above a `UIPageViewController`. Sometimes when I'm dragging the slider and my finger goes over the `UIPageViewController`, the `UISlider` stops being dragged. I have a feeling it's to do with the gesture recognisers for the `UIPageViewController` interfering with the UISlider gesture, but how can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: keep the UICollectionView view away from your UISlider. bcz this is not what a programmer has control on. this is the way things work.

Comment: @RockBalbao I need it above my UICollectionView, it shouldn't do this...

Comment: exactly. keep a fix constrain space between that even in small devices the finger doesn't slides to UICollectionView. Bcz as soon as it touches UICollectionView it loses its focus from slider. thus result in slider gets stop.

Comment: One other possibility - what does moving the slider control? For instance, if you are doing a large amount of main thread processing while moving th slider, it will "stutter". Another example is using GPU processing in the simulator (think update animate using Core Image) while adjusting a slider value - there's a notable lag in the simulator but no issue whatsoever on a real device.

Comment: @dfd The slider doesn't do anything until it's released so there is no processing issue. It just doesn't like being next to a UICollectionView. Maybe I could somehow disable touch on the UICollectionView until the slider is released?

Comment: Sorry just updated the question. I realised that it's a UIPageViewController below the UISlider. The UIPageViewController has UICollectionViews in.